# Filter number followed by dots out of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, filter

I would like to get rid of the numbers followed by a dot in an array.

I tried something like this.

```js
function parseMoves(){
  const pgnmoves = ["1.", "Nf3", "Nc6", "2.", "Bc4", "e6", "3."] // And so on.
  const reg = new RegExp('[0-9]+\.');  
  const filtered = pgnmoves.filter((x) => {
        return x != reg.test(x)
    })
  return filtered;
}
```

But that doesn't seem to do the trick, I am not so good with regular expressions.

This is the expected output:

```js
["Nf3", "Nc6", "Bc4", "e6"]
```

Thank you for helping out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is fine. You need to preserve items that fail the test, by using the `!` operator:

```js
function parseMoves(){
  const reg = /[0-9]+\./; // /^[0-9]+\.$/ - if you want to remove just items that start with a number and have a single dot at the end 
  
  return pgnmoves.filter((x) => !reg.test(x));
}

const pgnmoves = ["1.", "Nf3", "Nc6", "2.", "Bc4", "e6", "3."]; // And so on.

const result = parseMoves(pgnmoves);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
function parseMoves(){
 const pgnmoves = ["1.", "Nf3", "Nc6", "2.", "Bc4", "e6", "3."]
 const reg = new RegExp(/.*(\d\.)$/);  
 const filtered = pgnmoves.filter((x) => {
    return reg.test(x)==false;
 })
 return filtered;
}
```